# Can we sync users' photos from AzureAD to AD DS?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am wondering how I can go about syncing user profile Photos back to our Local Active Directory. We currently use Azure AD Connect (Latest Version).
Is this currently possible? If not ,is there any other good solutions to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We currently use Azure AD Connect (Latest Version). Is this currently
>   possible?

For now, Azure AD Connect does not support Syncing from Azure Active Directory to On-Premises AD DS. If this feature is important to you , you can upvote it in [this Custom Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/6455327-sync-azure-active-directory-down-to-on-premises-ad).

> If not ,is there any other good solutions to do this?

You can use these powershell scripts to do this but cost lots of time.

```
Connect-AzureAD
$photo = Get-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto -ObjectId <String>

Set-aduser -identity <ADUser> -replace @{thumbnailPhoto=([byte[]](($photo).PictureData))}
```

See more details about `Get-AzureADUserThumbnailPhoto` in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduserthumbnailphoto?view=azureadps-2.0).
See more details about `Set-aduser` in  [this document](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although the feedback looks like useless…